# How to remove a specific number from a file?

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have a text file which has following content

```
DESCRIPTION  ENABLED
 Tracker_EG32747257_0418_0618, {NAME => d, DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => NONE, BLOOMFILTER => ROW, REPLICATION_SCOPE => 0, COMPRESSION => LZ4, VERSIONS => 100000, MIN_VERSIONS => 0, TTL => 2419200 SECONDS (28 DAYS), KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => false, BLOCKSIZE => 65536, IN_MEMORY => false, BLOCKCACHE => true} true

1 row(s) in 0.0340 seconds

DESCRIPTION  ENABLED
 Tracker_EG38863805_0418_0618, {NAME => d, DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => NONE, BLOOMFILTER => ROW, REPLICATION_SCOPE => 0, COMPRESSION => LZ4, VERSIONS => 100000, MIN_VERSIONS => 0, TTL => 2419200 SECONDS (28 DAYS), KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => false, BLOCKSIZE => 65536, IN_MEMORY => false, BLOCKCACHE => true} true

1 row(s) in 0.0300 seconds

DESCRIPTION  ENABLED
 Session_EG32747257_0418_0618, {NAME => d, DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => NONE, BLOOMFILTER => ROW, REPLICATION_SCOPE => 0, COMPRESSION => LZ4, VERSIONS => 1, MIN_VERSIONS => 0, TTL => 2419200 SECONDS (28 DAYS), KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => false, BLOCKSIZE => 65536, IN_MEMORY => false, BLOCKCACHE => true} true

1 row(s) in 0.0270 seconds

DESCRIPTION  ENABLED
 Session_EG38863805_0418_0618, {NAME => d, DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => NONE, BLOOMFILTER => ROW, REPLICATION_SCOPE => 0, COMPRESSION => LZ4, VERSIONS => 1, MIN_VERSIONS => 0, TTL => 2419200 SECONDS (28 DAYS), KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => false, BLOCKSIZE => 65536, IN_MEMORY => false, BLOCKCACHE => true} true

1 row(s) in 0.0260 seconds....
```

Now I want to remove all 'DESCRIPTION' words and all 1's only (not any word which contains 1)

I am using this command,

```
sed 's/\(DESCRIPTION\|<1>\)//g'
```

It is removing all DESCRIPTION words but also removing all 1 digits in the file.

Comment: What is a "word"? In other words, may the `1` be limited only by whitespace and beginning/end of line? What about, TAB, braces, colon, underscore, comma, unicode-smileys?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using GNU `sed` (POSIX `sed` doesn't define `\|`). Then you can use perlish word boundaries, too, but you need to escape them to make `<>` special:

```
sed 's/\(DESCRIPTION\|\<1\>\)//g'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sed 's/^\(\<DESCRIPTION\>\|\<1\>\)//' infile
```

since you used `g`lobal option and it does remove all occurrences of 1 as well as it will do for `DESCRIPTION` too. As like above you need beginning of lines anchor `^` to remove the 1s and DESCRIPTION only if the line starts with those.

Comment: Thanks Afshin! it worked :) Just for curiosity, If the number would have been in the mid somewhere in the file, How can I remove that specific number?

Comment: `sed 's/only-first-specific-number//' infile`, or `sed 's/all-specific-number//g' infile`

Comment: This will remove `1` in `123`.